# Como obtener solo un valor de una consuta?

Tags: php

Creo que esto es de principiante (de hecho lo soy)...
Tengo una variable donde almaceno el resultado de una qry que hice a mi BD, específicamente solo sirve para extraer el ID de un usuario a través de un procedimiento almacenado en mi BD, el resultado de la qry debería arrojar solo 1 valor en caso de que algún usuario con el ID y la contraseña indicados en la qry existan

```
$qry = "CALL ComprobarID('$identificador','$pass');";
        $qryComprobacion = $conexion->query($qry);
```

El siguiente paso es extraer el valor que mi consulta trajo ya que en las paginas siguientes de mi sistema usare ese ID para traer el nombre completo de el usuario, aquí es donde tengo problemas, no consigo tomar ese valor de manera que lo pueda enviar a través de un método post con un input de tipo hidden o algo por el estilo, esto es lo que hice:

```
while ($row =mysql_fetch_row($qryComprobacion)) {
            echo $row['id_usuario'];
        }
```

según entiendo esto ultimo el ciclo recorre la tabla mientras esta tenga filas y después imprime el valor de la fila en la posición del id_usuario, esto es provisional para pruebas, idealmente esto le daría valor a una variable llamada $envID y esto es justo lo que no hace y solo me manda el sig. error:
**mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource**

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás trabajando con POO, continúa con ello. Utiliza mejor:

```
while ($row = $qryComprobacion->fetch_row()){
    echo $row['id_usuario'];
}
```